# Does dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 10 have any chance of stopping my laptop's screen flickering

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, screen

I have a Asus Laptop that came with Win10 pre-installed, after using it for about a year and a half, its screen started to occasionally flicker (it started doing that for the first time after continuous usage (google meet) of about 4 hours and now it starts doing it anywhere around the 30 mins to 2 hr mark).

I tried updating my graphics driver, and all other methods that came up online to no avail, then I decided to just reset my windows entirely and the problem still persists. I don't think it is a hardware issue as I've tried moving/shaking (slowly of course) the screen and that does not affect flickering. Also if I just close the apps I'm in when the flickering starts and just let my laptop be on the desktop page, it generally stops flickering (I also feel like the flickering also starts sooner if I'm watching a video as opposed to just using a static webpage)

My question is whether dual booting it and using Ubuntu instead of Windows (I just use my laptop to web surf and code in VSCode) has any chance of fixing the issue or is my only hope taking it to a service centre?

I'm sorry if this is not the right community to ask this in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s very likely to be a hardware issue, notwithstanding the failure to reproduce with shaking etc.
I think your best option to see if it is would be to ‘try Ubuntu’ from a live usb session rather than install it - if your problem persists then it’s a hardware problem. That should give you the answer without having to go through the fairly laborious process of creating a dual boot system, which would require partitioning your hard drive etc with some risks to your data.
You can download the iso file from [www.Ubuntu.com/download/desktop](http://www.Ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

This link will help you understand how to download and create a usb iso file:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Then change your bios / uefi settings to allow boot from usb (you’ll also need to disable fast start up in windows), put the usb in and restart your machine, choose ‘try Ubuntu’ and you should be able to test drive it to see if your screen flicker disappears. There are lots of answers on this site describing how to disable fast boot and how to change the boot order, but if you need help with that please say and I’ll edit the answer to incorporate that.

Comment: Ubuntu won't fix hardware issues, obviously, but this answer seems to suggest otherwise. A thorough re-write is in order. What should have been said is that a Ubuntu liver session can be used to troublashoot the problem and eventually rule out hardware if the issue doesn't present itself after a similar continuous usage.

Comment: Ok thanks @ChanganAuto. Edited my answer accordingly. I’d thought it was self-evident what I meant but you’re right it could be clearer.